# How do I manipulate orders of integration to cancel out a nested integral leaving me with only 1?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, improper-integrals

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are random variables and the only restriction on the probability density function $f_{A,B}(a,b)$ is $P(B>A) = 1$.  Also suppose $p(x) = P(A \leq x \leq B)$ where $x$ is $fixed$ and is not considered a random variable. How do you show the expected length of [A,B] interval is

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx$ ?

So by definition of expectation we know $E[length([A,B]] = $

$= E[b-a]  $

Target$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(B-A) f_{A,B}(a,b)dA dB $ ---> SHOW = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx$

So now we know our target.  Starting from :

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx = $

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(A \leq x \leq B)dx$ (by definition of $p(x)$)

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P( (A \leq x) \cap (B \geq x)dx$ (by definition of intersection)

This means A ranges from $(-\infty,x]$ and B ranges from $[x,\infty)$ and can be re-written as 2 integrals using the joint PDF $f_{A,B}$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{x} dA \int_{x}^{\infty} f_{A,B}dB$

This does not look like our target, but noticing that $\int_{a}^{b}dx = b-a$ I try to change the order of integration of $x$ and attempt to move it from outer-most to inner-most integral, pushing A, and B outward.

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} da \int_{a}^{\infty} f_{A,B} dB \int_{a}^{b} dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} da \int_{a}^{\infty} f_{A,B} dB (b-a)$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(b-a) da \int_{a}^{\infty} f_{A,B} dB $

So now I am much closer to my target, except I have an integral $\int_{a}^{\infty}$ that needs to somehow be canceled out.  I know this has something to do with $P(B \geq A)=1$ but I'm not sure how to make this last connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Tonelli: start from the identity between random variables $$\mathsf{length}[A,B]=\int_A^B\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathbf 1_{A\leqslant x\leqslant B}\,\mathrm dx.$$ Integrating both sides with respect to $P$ and exchanging the order of the integrals with respect to $P$ on $\Omega$ and with respect to $\mathsf{Leb}$ on $\mathbb R$ yields $$E(\mathsf{length}[A,B])=\int_{-\infty}^\infty E(\mathbf 1_{A\leqslant x\leqslant B})\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(A\leqslant x\leqslant B)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: I understand everything you did except in the beginning when you say $$\mathsf{length}[A,B]=\int_A^B\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathbf 1_{A\leqslant x\leqslant B}$$ . How do you know the indicator function of this is equal to the length of the interval [A,B] ?

Comment: The indicator function of this is NOT equal to the length, its integral is (and this seems rather obvious, no?).

Comment: Yes, but it is not obvious to me why the integral of the indicator is somehow equal to the length of the interval [A,B].  The indicator, if I understand correctly is 1 when the subscript holds true, 0 otherwise. Since this integral considers all possible values for $x$ between A and B the integral is 0 mostly everywhere except for when $x$ is between A and B.  But I'm still not seeing why we know for sure the integral is B-A.

Comment: ?? As you said, for every $a\leqslant b$, $\mathbf 1_{a\leqslant x\leqslant b}=0$ for every $x\lt a$ and every $x\gt b$ hence the integral on the RHS can be restricted to $[a,b]$, and $\mathbf 1_{a\leqslant x\leqslant b}=1$ for every $a\lt x\lt b$ hence the **second** equal sign. In turn, the first equal sign is clear, isn't it?

Comment: $$\mathsf{length}[A,B]=\int_A^B\mathrm dx $$ is definitely clear. So it seems to me that you are simply pulling out the bounds from the first integral and throwing them into the bounds for the indicator.  When you throw the bounds A and B into the indicator you can set the integral bounds from $(-\infty \infty)$.  This must hold true for all indicator functions.

Comment: This does hold true for every indicator function.